# Boolean with text without conversion

Tags: mesh, modifiers

I'm trying to find a way to make boolean operation between a mesh and a text with a solidify modifier **without applying a conversion** to the text.

I could copy the text, convert it to a mesh, then apply boolean modifier with this copy, but i lose the ability to change the text easily without repeating those operations.

Any idea?

Comment: booleans need real mesh objects. You can copy the text object and keep the original "hidden" for later edits (or different versions), and repeat.

Comment: But i need to repeat the copy, apply each time. I'm trying to find a woraround to that: i change text, boolean changes also. But thanks

Comment: imho there's no workaround, but if you have more than a few texts you could consider scripting this task...

Comment: It's what I am doing right now, but I was curious to know if it was possible to do that on native Blender, with a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [booltron addon](https://github.com/mrachinskiy/booltron) for this. It works with Curve and Text objects, but it isn't a modifier, it is a command. You select objects for a boolean operation (you can select more than 2) and press the operation name (intersect / difference / union).

Also, booltron fills holes before intersections.

This is the magic (I added a shortcut for the difference operation):
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tip. This is more convenient, but it is still a destructive workflow for text and curves. It does offer a non-destructive option for meshes.